# How to normalize an array of flat objects into its entities?

Tags: normalizr

Given an input that looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    id: 11,
    valueId: 22,
    valueDescription: 'Some value',
    referenceId: 33,
    referenceDescription: 'Some reference',
    groupId: 44,
    groupDescription: 'Some group'
  },
  {
    id: 55,
    valueId: 66,
    valueDescription: 'Another value',
    referenceId: 77,
    referenceDescription: 'Another reference',
    groupId: 88,
    groupDescription: 'Another group'
  }
]
```

And a desired output of:

```js
{
  entities: {
    types: {
      "11": { id: 11, valueId: 22, referenceId: 33, groupId: 44 },
      "55": { id: 55, valueId: 66, referenceId: 77, groupId: 88 },
    },
    values: {
      "22": { id: 22, description: "Some value" },
      "66": { id: 66, description: "Another value" },
    },
    references: {
      "33": { id: 33, description: "Some reference" },
      "77": { id: 77, description: "Another reference" },
    },
    groups: {
      "44": { id: 44, description: "Some group" },
      "88": { id: 88, description: "Another group" },
    }
  },
  result: [ 11, 55 ]
}
```

I'm not sure how I'd define Schemas for my 4 entity types that would pull multiple fields off of the flattened root object and also rename them. I see there's the `assignEntity` argument I can pass which I think I would use for the renaming part, but I'm not sure how I would define a `Schema` to indicate that one flat object becomes four entities.

Comment: normalizr is not designed to do something like this. You're essentially trying to split up a single discrete entity into multiple entities... Your input is already normalized. You'll need to write your own reducer for this.

Comment: @PaulArmstrong Well it's not actually normalized. It's denormalized into a flat structure. It does seem like normalizr does not have a way of handling this, but I thought maybe it was doable with some of the 'advanced' schema stuff and options.